# Is linear-time reduction symmetric?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

If a problem X reduces to a problem Y is the opposite reduction also possible? Say

X = Given an array tell if all elements are distinct

Y = Sort an array using comparison sort

Now, X reduces to Y in linear time i.e. if I can solve Y, I can solve X in linear time. Is the reverse always true? Can I solve Y, given I can solve X? If so, how?

By reduction I mean the following:

```
Problem X linear reduces to problem Y if X can be solved with:
a) Linear number of standard computational steps.
b) Constant calls to subroutine for Y.
```

Comment: Asked on CS beta. Answer is NO. http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11687/is-linear-time-reduction-symmetric

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I can solve a problem A in constant time O(1) but problem B has a best case exponential time solution O(2^n).  It is likely that I can come up with an insanely complex way of solving problem A in O(2^n) ("reducing" problem A to B) as well but if the answer to your question was "YES", I should then be able to make all exceedingly difficult problems solvable in O(1).  Surely, that cannot be the case!

Comment: Sure, you can reduce easy problems to hard ones.  That's not the tricky part.  I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Given the example above:

You can determine if all elements are distinct in `O(N)` if you back them up with a hash table.  Which allows you to check existence in `O(1)` + the overhead of the hash function (which generally doesn't matter).  IF you are doing a non-comparison based sort:

[sorting algorithm list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms)

[Specialized sort that is linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_sort#Analysis):

For simplicity, assume you're sorting a list of natural numbers. The sorting method is illustrated using uncooked rods of spaghetti:
    For each number x in the list, obtain a rod of length x. (One practical way of   choosing the unit is to let the largest number m in your list correspond to one full rod of spaghetti. In this case, the full rod equals m spaghetti units. To get a rod of length x, simply break a rod in two so that one piece is of length x units; discard the other piece.)

Once you have all your spaghetti rods, take them loosely in your fist and lower them to the table, so that they all stand upright, resting on the table surface. Now, for each rod, lower your other hand from above until it meets with a rod--this one is clearly the longest! Remove this rod and insert it into the front of the (initially empty) output list (or equivalently, place it in the last unused slot of the output array). Repeat until all rods have been removed.

So given a very specialized case of your problem, your statement would hold.  This will not hold in the general case though, which seems to be more what you are after.  It is very similar to when people think they have solved TSP, but have instead created a constrained version of the general problem that is solvable using a special algorithm.

Comment: Time and space complexity are interchangeable in many cases. Adding space can normally help reduce time. That's why in such problems it's usually stated (or implied) that additional space complexity is O(1)

Comment: @icepack Really?  Do you have a source for this?  I would like to read further regarding O(1) considerations of space complexity.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I had never heard of that either, but maybe IEEE papers omit it?

Comment: @BlackVegetable This stems out of complexity classes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity_class) - note it's not about time or space but about resources. As a private example, additional space is what actually reduces the time complexity of bucket-sort and alike.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand what you mean by reduction, let's say that I have a problem that I can solve in `O(N)` using an array of key/value pairs, that being the problem of looking something up from a list.  I can solve the same problem in `O(1)` by using a Dictionary.

Does that mean I can go back to my first technique, and use it to solve the same problem in `O(1)`?

I don't think so.

Comment: I clarified what reduction means